# How can I jump 2 words at a time throughout Windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Ever since I learned about using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with the arrow keys, backspace key, and delete key, I've felt my typing and editing productivity go up significantly.

I'd like to know if there's an easy way to define a shortcut to jump 2 words at a time, delete 2 words at a time, etc. that can be used natively throughout Windows like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> can?

If not, is it possible to implement via something like an AutoHotKey script? (eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to jump 2 words to the left or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete 2 words at a time?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoHotkey will do exactly that. Or you can tailor the shortcut keys to be context specific and only trigger when certain programs are active.

```
#Persistent

#IfWinActive      ; Every window. Change this line to tailor specificity
^!Left::SendInput, ^{Left 2}
^!Right::SendInput, ^{Right 2}
^!Backspace::SendInput, {Backspace 2}           ; delete two characters at a time
^!Backspace::SendInput, +^{Left}{Backspace}     ; delete a word at a time
^!Backspace::SendInput, +^{Left 2}{Backspace}   ; delete two words at a time
```

Pick only one of the three definitions for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> obviously.

Hotkey modifiers are in the AutoHotkey help file, but for quick reference, `^` is Control, `!` is Alt, `+` is Shift and `#` is the Windows button.

If you need to make a multi-line macro with `sleep` statements or something, start on the next line after the hotkey definition and end the macro with a `Return` statement.

```
^!Left::
    SendInput, ^{Left 2}
    Sleep 200                   ; Sleeping 10 to 200ms can help for 
                                ; reliability in multi-key-press functions,
                                ; depending on what you're doing
Return
```